# Async function waiting for inner function response

Tags: javascript, api

I have a async function which calls API endpoint (checkTimeslot), fetch response data and conditionally check that data.
Based on condition it continues and call another API endpoint (updateTimeslot or createTimeslot).

How can I call that function and force it to wait until all requests are done and only after that do something?

```
const addTimeslot = async (date, startTime, endTime) => {
  axios.post('/api/checkTimeslot', {timeslotDate: date.toISOString()})
  .then((response) => {
    const data = response.data;
    const slotObject = {
      start_time: startTime,
      end_time: endTime
    }

    if (data.status !== 'notfound') {
      const timeslotId = data.timeslot.id;

      axios.post('/api/updateTimeslot', {timeslotId: timeslotId, slot: slotObject})
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
    else {
      const timeslotId = v4();
      const timeslot = {
          id: timeslotId,
          day: date,
          slots: [slotObject]
      };
      axios.post('/api/createTimeSlot', timeslot)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      })
    }
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  })
}
```

Here I call the function and assume that ALL request are already completed, however it is not true.

```
  addTimeslot(date, startTime, endTime).then(() => {
    console.log('all completed');
  });
```

Comment: Return `axios.post` in `addTimeslot`. -- Also you're not returning any of the other `axios.post`

Comment: @evolutionxbox So I tried to return axios.post in if - else statement but it behaves in same way. It console.log('all completed)' before axios.post returns response.

Comment: @evolutionxbox You should return all of your axios.post calls

Comment: @RohanVeer thanks, but I didn't ask the question

Comment: @evolutionxbox oops. my bad.